# Is NodeJS a socket library for networking?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, sockets

Below is the server program(C) using socket functionality provided by `libC`

```
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/socket.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

main(){
int listfd,connfd,retval;
//pid_t childpid;
socklen_t clilen;
struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;

listfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
printf("listfd = %d ", listfd);
if (listfd < 0){
    perror("sock:");
    exit(1);
}
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(8004);

retval = bind(listfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
if(retval < 0){
    perror("bind:");
    exit(2);
}

listen(listfd, 5);

while(1){
    clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
    connfd = accept(listfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);
         printf(" connfd= %d",connfd);
    printf(" client connected \n");
    printf(" client's port no = %d\n",htons(cliaddr.sin_port));
    }
}
```

Is Node JS a similar socket library that helps JS users to communicate over sockets?

*Note: I would say, `node` is a framework but not library, because JS code is consumed by `node` unlike above C program invoking socket library functions*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node.js is a Javascript runtime (capable of running Javascript programs) that includes many library functions.  One such library function it includes is a socket library for making socket connections and communicating over those sockets.  That library in node.js is referred to as the "net" library which you can see documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

This is just one thing that node.js does and only one type of feature that it offers.  A node.js program does not have to use the net library if it does not need to.  Other libraries such as the http library are built on top of the net library to offer higher level networking functionality such as http servers and http requests.

node.js is conceptually similar to a Python implementation in the scope of what it covers.  Both include a language interpreter, a bunch of built-in libraries for core functions (networking, file I/O, etc...), the ability to run programs written in the supported language and the ability to include other libraries written for the environment or to create your own libraries.

Comment: So, v8 takes care of syntax errors in the code. Is that correct? nodeJS only provided libraries for networking/etc.. This is what I understand, when you say, JS runtime

Comment: @overexchange - I don't know what you mean by "takes care of syntax errors", but V8 is the engine that parses and runs Javascript code in node.js so it is the part of node.js that will first encounter syntax errors if they are present.

Comment: Yes, I mean, v8 takes care of parsing and running JS code. Does nodeJS at its core provide mulitple JS libaries for networking/crypto/etc....?

Comment: @overexchange - nodeJS provides many libraries built-in.  You can see a list [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/).  And, there are thousands of other libraries available on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) that you can easily use.

Comment: Is nodeJS similar to gnu `libC` that provides socket/encryption/file/etc.. functionality?

Comment: @overexchange - See the last paragraph I added to my answer.  node.js is more like other interpreted language environments (like Python) than it is like pure compiled languages like C.  libC is just a library for C programmers.   node.js has libraries in it, but it is much more than just a library.  For example, node.js also includes V8 for parsing and running Javascript, includes a system for communicating with native code, includes debugging capabilities, etc...  It's a complete programming runtime environment, not just a library.